CASA: Parsing RA and Dec output of imfit using au.imfitparseCLB
Currently working on a project in CASA where I want to make a position, velocity and intensity table for some images I've been analyzing, and applying imfit to get Gaussian fits. Specifically, these images have multiple channels, multiple regions, and some regions contain more than one Gaussian peak that I'm fitting (multiple components). Basically I want to throw all the relevant output data into a .txt file that reads channel, region, component, RA, RA uncertainty, Dec, Dec uncertainty, peak velocity, peak intensity, intensity uncertainty. However, since I want RA and Dec in hh:mm:ss.ss or dd:mm:ss.ss units, I was advised to use the au.imfitparseCLB tool in the analysis Utils package. I'm struggling a bit trying to integrate the two output forms and was wondering if anyone could help me out, please?
Below is the code I have so far, to read the relevant output data from imfit files:
import numpy as np
regions = [f'region{i}' for i in range(1, 7)]
channels = range(12, 19)
ref_channel_0 = 0  # Example reference channel 0
ref_channel_1 = 1  # Example reference channel 1
ref_velocity_0 = -4.03  # km/s, example reference velocity at channel 0
ref_velocity_1 = -2.83  # km/s, example reference velocity at channel 1
channel_width = ref_velocity_1 - ref_velocity_0  # km/s
all_results_txt = 'G10.29_all_fits.txt'
with open(all_results_txt, 'w') as all_file:
all_file.write("Region\tChannel\tComponent\tRA\tDec\tVelocity\tIntensity\tRA_Error\tDec_Error\tIntensity_Error\n")  # Header
for region in regions:
    for chan in channels:
        repnoise = imstat(imagename=f'G10.29pbcor_subcube_229_chan{chan}.image',
                          region='/Users/removedforprivacy/Desktop/Dissresearch/G10.29UNCORRECTED/G10.29_noise.crtf')['rms'][0]

        imfit_result = imfit(
            imagename=f'G10.29pbcor_subcube_229_chan{chan}.image',
            region=f'/Users/removedforprivacy/Desktop/Dissresearch/G10.29UNCORRECTED/G10.29_{region}.crtf',
            residual=f'G10.29_residual_chan{chan}_{region}',
            model=f'G10.29_model_chan{chan}_{region}',
            estimates=f'estimates_files/G10.29_estimates_chan{chan}_{region}.txt',
            logfile=f'G10.29_subcube_229_fits_chan{chan}_{region}.log',
            rms=repnoise,
            append=True
        )

        if 'results' in imfit_result:
            results = imfit_result['results']

            if isinstance(results, dict):
                for comp_key, comp in results.items():
                    if isinstance(comp, dict) and 'peak' in comp:
                        peak_intensity = comp['peak']['value']
                        intensity_error = comp['peak']['error']
                        

                        velocity = ref_velocity_0 + channel_width * (chan - ref_channel_0)

                        # Write all results to file
                        all_file.write(f"{region}\t{chan}\t{comp_key}\t{velocity:.2f}\t{peak_intensity:.2f}\t{intensity_error}\n")

print("All fits results have been saved to", all_results_txt)
